# Unable to create new New-CimInstance

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to stop/start Windows service remotely. However, if I remove the `-Computer` parameter, it is working fine in local machine. If I add the `-Computer` parameter, it is throwing an exception. Am I missing something?

```
New-CimInstance : Unable to resolve the parameter set name.
At D:\DevOps\Scripts\StartStopvNextService.ps1:6 char:16
+ ... yInstance = New-CimInstance -Namespace root/cimv2 -ClassName Win32_En ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-CimInstance], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.NewCimInstanceCommand
```

```
Param(
    [string]$Name,
    [string]$Computer
)
Import-Module CimCmdlets
$keyInstance = New-CimInstance -Namespace root/cimv2 -ClassName Win32_Service -Key @('Name') -Property @{Name=$Name;} -ComputerName $Computer -ClientOnly

Invoke-CimMethod $keyInstance -MethodName StartService
```

Comment: i cannot find a `-key` parameter for that cmdlet that accepts an array. there IS a `-KeyOnly` parameter, but that is a switch parameter and does not accept anything other than `-SwitchParameterName:$True` or `:$False`.

Comment: Why are you using `New-CimInstance` for this in the first place? Use the `*-Service` cmdlets via `Invoke-Command`.